# Filter not working when data has nulls-Teradata

Tags: null

I have a table Core_T1 with column Rec_stataus and all the values for Rec_status are Nulls.When I try to query as

```
Sel * from Core_t1 where Rec_status <>'DELETED'
```

table doesn't display any values. I have to incorporate this logic for future although we don't have any 'DELETED' records at the moment.Kindly let me know your inputs.

Data type of Rec_status :VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC

Comment: May be spell out SELECT *

Comment: It din't work..

Comment: Did you try != instead of <>

Comment: Yes,It din't work either

Comment: Any errors or just an empty result set?

Comment: No errors..Just empty result set ,although I have data for  Sel * from Core_t1  where Rec_status is null

Comment: Select * from Core_t1 where Rec_status NOT LIKE  'DELETED'

Comment: Din't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query a column that has NULL, because NULL = no value in the record.  In order for you to query it, you need to have some value in there, at the least an empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE function, like this:

```
Sel * from Core_t1 where COALESCE (Rec_status, '-') <>'DELETED'
```

All null values would turn to '-', which is not equal to 'DELETED', and hense all such rows would be accepted by WHERE.